# SPARQL - Select where non uri - Filtred non uri

Tags: sparql, rdf, dbpedia, virtuoso, linked-data

I am beginier in SPARQL / Linked Data. I have question about querying DBpedia. I understand how to select data where filtering condition is URI. Now, I need to query about data, when key factor is not a resource. It is string.

I want select instuments used by Joan Jett. 
I am using this endpoint: http://dbpedia.org/snorq

**Query:** - with error

```
SELECT ?instrument WHERE
{
?person a dbo:MusicalArtist .
?person dbp:instrument ?instrument .
?person dbo:alias : 'Joan_Jett'.
}
```

**Another version:** - with no data

```
SELECT distinct ?instrument WHERE
{
?person a dbo:MusicalArtist .
?person dbp:instrument ?instrument .
?person dbo:alias ?alias.
FILTER regex(str(?alias), "Joan_Jett") .
}
```

I am trying to do it by myself. However, If someone help me with that, I will be wonder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First version**

```
SELECT ?instrument WHERE
{
?person a dbo:MusicalArtist .
?person dbp:instrument ?instrument .
?person dbo:alias "Joan Jett"@en.
}
```

**Second version**

```
SELECT distinct ?instrument WHERE
{
?person a dbo:MusicalArtist .
?person dbo:instrument ?instrument .
?person dbo:alias ?alias.
FILTER regex(str(?alias), "Joan Jett") .
}
```

NB. `dbp:instrument` is not the same as `dbo:instrument`.

Comment: So, I was close. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match an RDF literal, you have to follow it's [definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#section-Graph-Literal), i.e. basically (in RDF 1.0)

`"LEXICAL_FORM"^^<DATATYPE_URI>`

resp. if a language tag exists

`"LEXICAL_FORM"@LANGUAGE_TAG`

```sql
SELECT distinct ?instrument WHERE 
{
?person a dbo:MusicalArtist ;
        dbp:instrument ?instrument ;
        dbo:alias "Joan Jett"@en .
}
```